# Issues writing files on iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, filesystems, nsfilemanager

I'm fighting with the following error **NSCocoaErrorDomain 513** reported by a very small number of users:

```
Unable to create directory at path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EBE2C5D8-5AEC-4D62-9393-B19CAD598FE5/Documents/documents/FF2F88FB-2C07-4FA3-988E-58AD5C21F659/9A02F8A0-74EB-4ED6-81B6-4F40653856D3. 
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “9A02F8A0-74EB-4ED6-81B6-4F40653856D3” in the folder “FF2F88FB-2C07-4FA3-988E-58AD5C21F659”." 
UserInfo={
    NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EBE2C5D8-5AEC-4D62-9393-B19CAD598FE5/Documents/documents/FF2F88FB-2C07-4FA3-988E-58AD5C21F659/9A02F8A0-74EB-4ED6-81B6-4F40653856D3,
    NSUnderlyingError=0x15e09de00 {
        Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain 
        Code=13 "Permission denied"
    }
}
```

This error means that the directory cannot be created because of a permission error. That's where I'm lost as the only reason I can see would be if I'm creating a file outside of my app's sandbox.

The code generating this error:

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *directory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:documentsPathAndUUIDs];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:directory 
                               withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                                attributes:nil            
                                                     error:&error]) {
    NSError(@"Unable to create directory at path %@. Error: %@", directory, error);
}
```

A couple things worth noting:

- This path isn't saved, it's regenerated every time, so it's not as if the app container had changed between installs;
- The users seem to have available disk space;
- This affects at least iOS 9 (I don't have enough reports to know if it also affects iOS 10)

Would anyone have a hint of why this could happen?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sudo/chown privileges on /var? If not and you're running an OS post Mavericks, you may need to restart in safety mode and disable CSRUtil

[Documentation on CSRUtil](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html)

Comment: my question is related to iOS